# Metaphors for air

Tags: metaphors, figurative

I am in search of a nice metaphor for air — I find nothing when searching online, and currently nothing seems to be coming to mind.

The only thing I have found is:

> *Air is the ether of space*

but I don't really understand this.

Do you have any nice air metaphors? Or is there some way to explain the above which I am not aware of?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has no definitive, and many possible answers (of varying quality). Writing advice. Probably best asked on _Writing_.

Comment: You have to provide a context. Where and how will the metaphor be used? Without that, there are far too many possibilities.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: How would you go about constructing a metaphor for air describing its agency in aiding a fire?

Comment: @Stockfish A simile is a specific kind of metaphor. In this case, assuming a simile is fine (that needs to be clarified in the question), just think of any number of situations where somebody or something is helped, encouraged, or enraged, and that agent is what the air is like. ("*Like a belligerent coach, the wind rushed to bully the fire to greater heights.*")

Comment: Note that I am not providing my example in the previous comment as an answer. I have already voted to close this question as lacking enough detail to provide an objective single answer.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Wonderful! I like that! Yeah, that I know.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what exactly the air is doing. A light breeze could be fingers in your hair; on a still humid day, the air could be a weight pressing down on you. In a gale, the air might be a battering ram of force, or a playful giant uprooting trees and hurling them for fun. If it's cold outside the air might be Jack Frost's breath, or a freezer's chill. If it's a hot day it might be a delicious sauna, or an oppressive oven of heat. Your exact context matters quite a lot; think about what you want to say about the air, then make up a metaphor that fits. If you're discussing, say, how a sounds travels through air, you could liken it to a postman; "the still air delivered her whispers straight to my ears". If you're talking about someone short of breath, the air could be a doctor; "I lay gasping on the shore as the air worked to heal my oxygen starved body."

Comment: For once, I've upvoted an answer to a question I'm probably about to C-V on 'too broad / open to multiple opinion-based suggestions, some cheesy, some weird, some very appealing' grounds.

Answer (score 0):

The spirit? “Air is the spirit of life”?

The mention of ether comes from a time when scientists supposed space to be filled with an “ether” that was the medium through which light travelled. It was later realised that no such concept was needed to explain electromagnetic radiation of any sort, including light. Nor was there any evidence for the existence of ether. But the concept remains as a useful mental image.